# Interfacing temperature sensor(TMP175) with STM32F407 using I2C Communication protocol

Tags: embedded, keil, stm32f4discovery, mbed

I am trying to set up my STM32 microcontroller with HAL
 libraries to read from a TMP175 temperature sensor using i2c.

However, I am able to read the value from the single sensor but I wrote the code for 4 TMP175 temperature sensor.

I am getting only single current sensor value.

I referred the Datasheet of TMP175: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tmp75.pdf

I am using Keil IDE version 5 for programming.

Here is how I have done it so far using HAL libraries:

```
void StartDefaultTask(void const * argument)
{
HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, (uint8_t) 0x90 , (uint8_t) CONFIG_REG  , (uint8_t) 1,Config, 1, 1000);
HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, (uint8_t)0x90 , (uint8_t) thigh  , (uint8_t) 1, THigh, 1, 1000);
HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, (uint8_t) 0x90 , (uint8_t) tlow  , (uint8_t) 1, TLow, 1, 1000);
HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, (uint8_t) 0x91, (uint8_t)CONFIG_REG , (uint8_t) 1, &ConfigReg[0], 1, 1000);
printf("    configreg==%x\t \r",ConfigReg[0]);

HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, (uint8_t) 0x91, (uint8_t) tlow, (uint8_t) 1,TLowReg, 2, 1000);
TLow1=(TLowReg[0]<<4);
TLow1|=(TLowReg[1]>>4);
TL=TLow1*0.0625;
printf(" Lower Limit Temperature=%f deg celsius \r ", TL);
HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, (uint8_t) 0x91, (uint8_t) thigh, (uint8_t) 1,THighReg, 2, 1000);
THigh1=(THighReg[0]<<4);
THigh1|=(THighReg[1]>>4);
TH=THigh1*0.0625;
printf(" upper Limit Temperature=%f deg celsius \r", TH);       
HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, (uint8_t) 0x91, (uint8_t) TEMPERATURE, (uint8_t) 1, TempReg, 2, 1000);
Shift=TempReg[0]<<4;
Shift|=TempReg[1]>>4;
Temp=Shift*0.0625;
printf("Temperature=%f deg Celsius \r",Temp);

}

/* StartTask02 function */
void StartTask02(void const * argument)
{
HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, (uint8_t) 0x9a , (uint8_t) CONFIG_REG  , (uint8_t) 1,Config, 1, 1000);
HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, (uint8_t)0x9a , (uint8_t) thigh  , (uint8_t) 1, THigh, 2, 1000);
HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, (uint8_t) 0x9a , (uint8_t) tlow  , (uint8_t) 1, TLow, 2, 1000);
HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, (uint8_t) 0x01, (uint8_t)CONFIG_REG , (uint8_t) 1, &ConfigReg[0], 1, 1000);
printf("    configreg==%x\t \r",ConfigReg[0]);
HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, (uint8_t) 0x02, (uint8_t) tlow, (uint8_t) 1,TLowReg, 2, 1000);
TLow1=(TLowReg[0]<<4);
TLow1|=(TLowReg[1]>>4);
TL=TLow1*0.0625;
printf(" Lower Limit Temperature=%f deg celsius \r ", TL);
HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, (uint8_t) 0x03, (uint8_t) thigh, (uint8_t) 1,THighReg, 2, 1000);
THigh1=(THighReg[0]<<4);
THigh1|=(THighReg[1]>>4);
TH=THigh1*0.0625;
printf(" upper Limit Temperature=%f deg celsius \r", TH);   
HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, (uint8_t) 0x00, (uint8_t) TEMPERATURE, (uint8_t) 1, TempReg, 2, 1000);
Shift=TempReg[0]<<4;
Shift|=TempReg[1]>>4;
Temp=Shift*0.0625;

printf("Temperature=%f deg Celsius \r",Temp);

}

/* StartTask03 function */
void StartTask03(void const * argument)
{
HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, (uint8_t) 0x9c , (uint8_t) CONFIG_REG  , (uint8_t) 1,Config, 1, 1000);
HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, (uint8_t)0x9c , (uint8_t) thigh  , (uint8_t) 1, THigh, 2, 1000);
HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, (uint8_t) 0x9c , (uint8_t) tlow  , (uint8_t) 1, TLow, 2, 1000);
HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, (uint8_t) 0x01, (uint8_t)CONFIG_REG , (uint8_t) 1, &ConfigReg[0], 1, 1000);
printf("    configreg==%x\t \r",ConfigReg[0]);
HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, (uint8_t) 0x02, (uint8_t) tlow, (uint8_t) 1,TLowReg, 2, 1000);
TLow1=(TLowReg[0]<<4);
TLow1|=(TLowReg[1]>>4);
TL=TLow1*0.0625;
printf(" Lower Limit Temperature=%f deg celsius \r ", TL);
HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, (uint8_t) 0x03, (uint8_t) thigh, (uint8_t) 1,THighReg, 2, 1000);
THigh1=(THighReg[0]<<4);
THigh1|=(THighReg[1]>>4);
TH=THigh1*0.0625;
printf(" upper Limit Temperature=%f deg celsius \r", TH);       
HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, (uint8_t) 0x00, (uint8_t) TEMPERATURE, (uint8_t) 1, TempReg, 2, 1000);
Shift=TempReg[0]<<4;
Shift|=TempReg[1]>>4;
Temp=Shift*0.0625;
printf("Temperature=%f deg Celsius \r",Temp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong slave/device address in the calls to `HAL_I2C_Mem_Read()`.  For example, in `StartTask02()` you call `HAL_I2C_Mem_Write()` with device address 0x9a but then you call `HAL_I2C_Mem_Read()` with device address 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, and 0x00.  Why did you do this differently than what you did in `StartDefaultTask()`?

I would suggest you use some #defines, like this:

```
#define TMP175_1_I2C_ADDRESS 0x90
#define TMP175_2_I2C_ADDRESS 0x9a
#define TMP175_3_I2C_ADDRESS 0x9c

HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, TMP175_2_I2C_ADDRESS , (uint8_t) tlow  , (uint8_t) 1, TLow, 2, 1000);
HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, TMP175_2_I2C_ADDRESS, (uint8_t)CONFIG_REG , (uint8_t) 1, &ConfigReg[0], 1, 1000);
```

I believe you can pass the same raw address to `HAL_I2C_Mem_Write()` and `HAL_I2C_Mem_Read()` because the HAL functions will set the least significant R/W bit appropriately.

Comment: If i run the code for single temperature sensor , am getting the correct output but if i integrate the 4 temperature sensor am not getting value ...           After integrate not even single value is coming..                                                    I follow the your instruction that  device address still not getting

Comment: @sirisha You'll have to post the new code.  And show how the `StartTask02` and `StartTask03` functions are being called.

Comment: `#define TMP175_1_I2C_ADDRESS 0x90`
`#define TMP175_2_I2C_ADDRESS 0x9a`
`#define TMP175_3_I2C_ADDRESS 0x9c`
`#define TMP175_4_I2C_ADDRESS 0x9e`                                                       This define function i used..

Comment: for `startTask02` i used the below code formate:     `HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, TMP175_2_I2C_ADDRESS , (uint8_t) CONFIG_REG  , (uint8_t) 1,Config, 1,1000);``HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, TMP175_2_I2C_ADDRESS , (uint8_t) thigh  , (uint8_t) 1, THigh, 2, 1000);`
 `HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, TMP175_2_I2C_ADDRESS , (uint8_t) tlow  , (uint8_t) 1, TLow, 2, 1000);`
`HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, TMP175_2_I2C_ADDRESS , (uint8_t)CONFIG_REG , (uint8_t) 1, &ConfigReg[0], 1, 1000);`         similary for the `starttask03` with the address of 0x9c